# Age in years from select tag dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing a small project for work, and I created a small HTML text file. Looking to parse the given date of birth from dropdown menus into an age that I can then run through a control flow.

I've created the dropdown lists to select the date of birth using the `<select>` tag, then option values. Afterwards added a submit button using the `<input type="submit">`

I'm trying to do this without using any external libraries or frameworks.

How can I get the person's age in only years?

Comment: Provide some code.

Comment: See [jquery date picker dropdown](https://codepen.io/beaherraez/pen/QmPxKV)

Comment: At least show your attempt, so others can help you with the part you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

it's not exactly and i suggest you to use a library but here is a proximation:

```js
function calcAge() {
  let day = document.getElementById('day').value;
  let month = document.getElementById('month').value;
  let year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  let birthday = new Date(year, month, day);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ~~(((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000)));
}
```

```html
<label id="date_of_birth">Date of Birth:<br />
    <select class="first" name="date_of_birth:day" tabindex="7" id="day">
        <option value="">
            <!-- -->
        </option>
        <option value="01">1</option>
        <option value="02">2</option>
        <option value="03">3</option>
        <option value="04">4</option>
        <option value="05">5</option>
        <option value="06">6</option>
        <option value="07">7</option>
        <option value="08">8</option>
        <option value="09">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select name="date_of_birth:mon" tabindex="8" id="month">
        <option value="">
            <!-- -->
        </option>
        <option value="01">Jan</option>
        <option value="02">Feb</option>
        <option value="03">Mar</option>
        <option value="04">Apr</option>
        <option value="05">May</option>
        <option value="06">Jun</option>
        <option value="07">Jul</option>
        <option value="08">Aug</option>
        <option value="09">Sep</option>
        <option value="10">Oct</option>
        <option value="11">Nov</option>
        <option value="12">Dec</option>
    </select>
    <select name="date_of_birth:year" tabindex="9" id="year">
        <option value="">
            <!-- -->
        </option>
        <option value="1920">1920</option>
        <option value="1921">1921</option>
        <option value="1922">1922</option>
        <option value="1923">1923</option>
        <option value="1924">1924</option>
        <option value="1925">1925</option>
        <option value="1926">1926</option>
        <option value="1927">1927</option>
        <option value="1928">1928</option>
        <option value="1929">1929</option>
        <option value="1930">1930</option>
        <option value="1931">1931</option>
        <option value="1932">1932</option>
        <option value="1933">1933</option>
        <option value="1934">1934</option>
        <option value="1935">1935</option>
        <option value="1936">1936</option>
        <option value="1937">1937</option>
        <option value="1938">1938</option>
        <option value="1939">1939</option>
        <option value="1940">1940</option>
        <option value="1941">1941</option>
        <option value="1942">1942</option>
        <option value="1943">1943</option>
        <option value="1944">1944</option>
        <option value="1945">1945</option>
        <option value="1946">1946</option>
        <option value="1947">1947</option>
        <option value="1948">1948</option>
        <option value="1949">1949</option>
        <option value="1950">1950</option>
        <option value="1951">1951</option>
        <option value="1952">1952</option>
        <option value="1953">1953</option>
        <option value="1954">1954</option>
        <option value="1955">1955</option>
        <option value="1956">1956</option>
        <option value="1957">1957</option>
        <option value="1958">1958</option>
        <option value="1959">1959</option>
        <option value="1960">1960</option>
        <option value="1961">1961</option>
        <option value="1962">1962</option>
        <option value="1963">1963</option>
        <option value="1964">1964</option>
        <option value="1965">1965</option>
        <option value="1966">1966</option>
        <option value="1967">1967</option>
        <option value="1968">1968</option>
        <option value="1969">1969</option>
        <option value="1970">1970</option>
        <option value="1971">1971</option>
        <option value="1972">1972</option>
        <option value="1973">1973</option>
        <option value="1974">1974</option>
        <option value="1975">1975</option>
        <option value="1976">1976</option>
        <option value="1977">1977</option>
        <option value="1978">1978</option>
        <option value="1979">1979</option>
        <option value="1980">1980</option>
        <option value="1981">1981</option>
        <option value="1982">1982</option>
        <option value="1983">1983</option>
        <option value="1984">1984</option>
        <option value="1985">1985</option>
        <option value="1986">1986</option>
        <option value="1987">1987</option>
        <option value="1988">1988</option>
        <option value="1989">1989</option>
        <option value="1990">1990</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
    </select>
</label>
<button onclick="calcAge()">
    calculate
</button>
<br>
<div id="result" text="asdaaa">
</div>
```